# GitHub for Windows crashes at launch

Tags: windows, github, github-for-windows

Recently upadated computer and GitHub for Windows will not launch anymore. I have uninstalled and reinstalled GitHub a couple time and I am running the latest version 2.0.2. Anyone have any ideas what could be causing the issue. Errors from Windows 7 event viewer are below.

".NET Runtime" Error

```
Application: GitHub.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.EntryPointNotFoundException
Stack:
   at Akavache.Sqlite3.Internal.SQLite3.Open(Byte[], IntPtr ByRef, Int32, IntPtr)
   at Akavache.Sqlite3.Internal.SQLiteConnection..ctor(System.String, Akavache.Sqlite3.Internal.SQLiteOpenFlags, Boolean)
   at Akavache.Sqlite3.Internal.SQLiteConnectionPool+Entry..ctor(Akavache.Sqlite3.Internal.SQLiteConnectionString, Akavache.Sqlite3.Internal.SQLiteOpenFlags)
   at Akavache.Sqlite3.Internal.SQLiteConnectionPool+<>c__DisplayClass8.<Reset>b__7(Int32)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)
   at Akavache.Sqlite3.Internal.SQLiteConnectionPool+<>c__DisplayClass8.<Reset>b__5()
   at System.Reactive.Linq.Observαble.Finally`1+_+<>c__DisplayClass1[[System.Reactive.Unit, System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.1.30214.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].<Run>b__0()
   at System.Reactive.Disposables.AnonymousDisposable.Dispose()
   at System.Reactive.Disposables.SingleAssignmentDisposable.set_Disposable(System.IDisposable)
   at System.Reactive.Producer`1[[System.Reactive.Unit, System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.1.30214.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].Run(System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler, State<System.Reactive.Unit>)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ScheduledItem`2[[System.TimeSpan, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Reactive.Producer`1+State[[System.Reactive.Unit, System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.1.30214.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.1.30214.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].InvokeCore()
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.CurrentThreadScheduler+Trampoline.Run(System.Reactive.Concurrency.SchedulerQueue`1<System.TimeSpan>)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.CurrentThreadScheduler.Schedule[[System.Reactive.Producer`1+State[[System.Reactive.Unit, System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.1.30214.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.1.30214.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](State<System.Reactive.Unit>, System.TimeSpan, System.Func`3<System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler,State<System.Reactive.Unit>,System.IDisposable>)
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.LocalScheduler.Schedule[[System.Reactive.Producer`1+State[[System.Reactive.Unit, System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.1.30214.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.1.30214.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](State<System.Reactive.Unit>, System.Func`3<System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler,State<System.Reactive.Unit>,System.IDisposable>)
   at System.Reactive.Producer`1[[System.Reactive.Unit, System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.1.30214.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].SubscribeRaw(System.IObserver`1<System.Reactive.Unit>, Boolean)
   at System.Reactive.Producer`1[[System.Reactive.Unit, System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.1.30214.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].Subscribe(System.IObserver`1<System.Reactive.Unit>)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.QueryLanguage.LastOrDefaultInternal[[System.Reactive.Unit, System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.1.30214.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](System.IObservable`1<System.Reactive.Unit>, Boolean)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.QueryLanguage.Wait[[System.Reactive.Unit, System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.1.30214.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](System.IObservable`1<System.Reactive.Unit>)
   at System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.Wait[[System.Reactive.Unit, System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.1.30214.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](System.IObservable`1<System.Reactive.Unit>)
   at Akavache.Sqlite3.Internal.SQLiteConnectionPool..ctor(Akavache.Sqlite3.Internal.SQLiteConnectionString, Akavache.Sqlite3.Internal.SQLiteOpenFlags, System.Nullable`1<Int32>)
   at Akavache.Sqlite3.Internal.SQLiteAsyncConnection..ctor(System.String, System.Nullable`1<Akavache.Sqlite3.Internal.SQLiteOpenFlags>, Boolean)
   at Akavache.Sqlite3.SqlitePersistentBlobCache..ctor(System.String, System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler)
   at GitHub.AppStartup.StartupSequence.InitializeApplication()
   at GitHub.App..ctor()
   at GitHub.App.Main()
```

Application Error

```
Faulting application name: GitHub.exe, version: 2.0.2.0, time stamp: 0x53972d34
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18409, time stamp: 0x53159a86
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c42d
Faulting process id: 0x1ed8
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf84e36de108b1
Faulting application path: C:\Users\scottd\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\9PJ6YVKX.4BZ\BHB0QYNT.T50\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0002.0000_1abc1ed917fcef94\GitHub.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: ac4bef10-f0d6-11e3-89dd-1c4bd60b2a1a
```

Windows Updates

```
Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2515325)
Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2923545)
Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2647753)
```

Comment: Same here! Did you find a solution yet? I've also contacted support, still waiting for a reply...

Comment: I got the same problem.

Comment: I heard from someone at GitHub last night and he mentioned that had a few others contact them with the same issue. He is led to believe they are colliding with another version of SQLite. I will update if I hear of a fix or find something new.

Comment: I had such a problem too. Now I can run the software but it is impossible to sync my commited changes: it claims that they are uncommited !

Comment: Since the version 2.0.8 it is [corrected](https://windows.github.com/release-notes.html), install the new version and it will work.

Comment: New link for release notes, https://desktop.github.com/release-notes/windows/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments from AB & Stéphane provided the hint:

I found a much older sqlite3.dll in c:\Windows\SysWOW64 which is apparently being loaded in path instead of c:\Users\[User]\AppData\Apps\2.0\[Blah]\[Blah]\gith..ion_[blah]\NativeBinaries\sqlite3.dll

In my case, I have no idea what might be looking for the older library, so to hedge my bets, I renamed the older version to sqlite3.dlx and put a copy of Github's sqlite3.dll in SysWOW64. That puts me at risk of breaking Github again in the future unless they can be more careful loading their libraries.

But to hit it with a sledgehammer, just remove or rename c:\Windows\SysWOW64\sqlite3.dll

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. That took care of it for us.

Comment: See @Llopis comment above it appears to be fixed as of version [2.0.6](https://windows.github.com/release-notes.html)